# Print Array Index Which Contains Any Number + "€"

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array

```
['95.65€', '', '10', '€', '5€']
```

I just want to print the index which **contains any number and the € symbol**.

For example, that would be for the top array 95.65€ and 5€.

But how?

```
content = ['95.65€', '', '10', '€', '5€']

for i in content:
    if "€" in i: # And Number??
        print(i)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to print a string after you `replace` the symbol with a blank string?

Comment: the same suggestions in [your last](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70327422/1324033) post would still apply here

Comment: Yes, but the other comments about using a regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ['95.65€', '', '10', '€', '5€']

for idx, ele in enumerate(a):
    if '€' in ele and any(c.isdigit() for c in ele):
        print(f'index {idx}: {ele}')

# Output:
# index 0: 95.65€
# index 4: 5€
```